# Add object for all missing enum to the List<object>

Tags: c#, list, enums

I Have a scenario where I have a method that returns `List<CategoriesDto>`, and I need to ensure that it contains the list of all the Categories mentioned in the `CategoriesEnum`. If any Categories are missing from the list, we must add them.

Sample code

**Class#**

```
public class CategoriesDto
{
    public CategoriesEnum Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; } = false;
}
```

**Enum#**

```
public enum CategoriesEnum
{
    TV,
    AC,
    Car,
    Fridge
}
```

**Case#**

Let's assume that below is the `List<CategoriesDto>` we have,

```
var categoriesList = new List<CategoriesDto>
    {
        new()
        {
            Name = CategoriesEnum.TV,
            Enabled = true,
        },
        new()
        {
            Name = CategoriesEnum.AC,
            Enabled = true,
        }
    };
```

In this case, the method will check the missing object from the enum `CategoriesEnum`(in this case (`Car, Fridge`)). It will add them to the list `categoriesList` with the default value for the `Enabled` property as `false`.

Comment: Where's your problem? What did you do already? We're not doing your work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Enum.GetValues<TEnum>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-7.0#system-enum-getvalues-1) to get enum values and then some LINQ on top. For example:

```cs
var missing = Enum.GetValues<CategoriesEnum>()
    .Except(categoriesList.Select(dto => dto.Name))
    .Select(e => new CategoriesDto
    {
        Name = e
    });

categoriesList.AddRange(missing);
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is [`Enum.GetValues()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-7.0):

```
var cats = Enum.GetValues<CategoriesEnum>().
      Where(e => !caterogiesList.Any(c => c.Name == e));
foreach(var cat in cats)
{
    categoriesList.Add(new CategoriesDto() {Name = cat, Enabled = false});
}
```

Comment: Either cast or use generic `Enum.GetValues` version.

Comment: @GuruStron Was already fixing, saw the error when I looked up the reference to link it.

Comment: Also, I like your `Except()` option better than my Any(), but I'd remove the `ToList()` call: it's not needed, and will hurt ram use.

Comment: Updated. Was posting the safeties variant which will not be depended on potential laziness. Though in this case it seems to be redundant.

Comment: Both the answer is correct and worked for me. Thank you